# Add 7 days to datetime (rather than just date) in php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm currently getting a datetime from a form that is stored in mysql like this:

```
2013-03-18 09:00:00
```

However for the function I am building, I'm inserting an event into a calendar where each week is less than the final week, essentially the insert is replicated except that the start date has changed.

So I get the post like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo $start = $_POST['startDT'].':00';
}
```

This works. So does the function for putting it in for one week only. What I'm stuck on, is replicating it across weeks.

So my function looks like this:

```
if ($allYear = "yes")
{
    //Get Week in question - gives me the week number for that particular week
    $startW = getStartWeek($start);
        //It'll always be week 56 as the end week of the year
    $endW = 56;
        //while $i is less than or equal to 56, do it and add 1 to $i
    for($i = $startW; $i <= $endw; $i++)
    {
        $query = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `Events`(`Start`, `End`, `Group`, `Unit`, `Type`, `Room`, `Lecturer`) VALUES ('$start', '$end', '$group', '$unit', '$type', '$room', '$lecturer')");
        /*Here is where I'd add code to make the datetime, for example:
        * $start is 2013-03-18 09:00:00 and $end is 2013-03-18 10:00:00
        * I want $start in the next iteration to be 2013-03-25 09:00:00 and $end
        * to be 2013-03-25 10:00:00. I then want $start to be 2013-04-01 09:00:00
        * on the iteration after that. And so on.
        */
        $start += strtotime("+1 week");
        $end += strtotime("+1 week");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are already using prepared statements why not continue best practice and use placeholders so that your query is not vulnerable to injection attacks?  (...remember StackOverflow readers/researchers are watching/learning from the content posted on this site)  Binding and executing will work quite nicely with your loop.  For the record, **prepare only once** (prior to looping) then **bind** and **execute** in your loop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add a week to date this way:

```
$date = "2013-07-04 08:10:25";
$date = strtotime($date);
$date = strtotime("+7 day", $date);
echo date('Y-M-d h:i:s', $date);
```

Answer (score 14):

You should really use the DateTime class which helps with dates manipulation. http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2013-03-18 09:00:00');
$date->modify('+1 week');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```